# Are newborn babies infected?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In *The Walking Dead* we learn early on (S2 if memory serves) that everyone is infected and the infection only takes effect after death but I don't recall if new born babies are infected.

My question in about babies conceived after the 'outbreak/epidemic' (post Rick waking up out of his coma) are born infected, so not directly asking about Judith as she was conceived before.

I binged watched so may not have absorbed every little detail and still haven't watched S9 yet as can't stand waiting a week between episodes so no spoilers please.

Comment: Same question on SFF: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/109279/98028

Comment: @jenayah  are you sure it's the same? Similar but mine is specific to post virus conception where as the one you highlighted doesn't ask that and none of the comments/answers I read cover it either. Just saying.

Comment: Yeah I should probably​have written "related" instead, in any case that was to link info together not to say there was a problem with your question​ :) (though the "we dunno" answer probably still stands)

Comment: It's possible (granted I haven't read any books/comics, just seen the series up to S8) that the writers haven't alluded to that yet. I've watched all the way through to S8 twice and STILL hvaen't seen anything either alluding to that, @Seamusthedog

Comment: FWIW I've read all the comics and while there have been some post-infection-conceived babies I don't remember them being killed, or it not being worthy of a notice. So maybe not enough info there as well

Comment: I can't put this as an answer since I don't know for sure, but it stands to reason that if everyone is infected (which they are, we learned that when Bob met his demise), then everyone conceived by two infected parents stands a good chance of being infected, but not a 100% chance.  It would now become genetic, and there are cases of genetic anomalies like children born with different eye or hair color than their parents.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: not all diseases transfer to the children, even if both parents are infected. Though in the case of the Walking Dead's disease, it is possible: babies use the immune system of their mother before birth, and it is known (Word of God?) that the zombie virus lowers people's immune system (cue people that die quickly from diseases that would be inocuituous in our world). But genetics does not work as you write it.